# Help proving an inequality in calculus $0 \leq \frac{x\ln(x)}{x^2-1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

So as the title states, I need help with proving this inequality:

$$0 \leq \frac{x\ln(x)}{x^2-1}\leq \frac{1}{2} $$
Also an important thisn is that $x>1$.

So I thought I could look different kinds fo x, but it's a subject of calculus, so perhaps it's related to Lagrange's or Rolle's theorem, but i cannot get an idea, i tried changing the inequality but it's not really working, so any help with solution would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function  $f(x) = \cfrac{x\ln(x)}{x^2-1}$   is positive and  monotone decreasing for $x\ge 1$ because 
$$f'(x) = -\frac{x^2(\ln(x)-1)+\ln(x)+1}{(x^2-1)^2} < 0$$
for $x > 1$. The maximium of f(x) is therefore $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot$

Comment: so maximum is found using derivatives as well?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife Not directly; to evaluate $f(1)$, a limit must be calculated.

Comment: Kind of, you compute the limit with e.g. d'Hospital - using the second derivatives of $x\ln(x)$ and $x^2-1.$

Comment: It is not a requirement to use L'Hopital's rule; e.g., $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x+1} \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x - \log 1}{x - 1} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \log x \right]_{x = 1} = \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{x}\right]_{x=1} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: When $x = 1$, $f'(x)$ is indeterminate, although if we fill in the singularity to make $f$ continuous, then $f'(1) = 0$, not strictly negative.  Furthermore, there is insufficient justification for the sign of the numerator of $f'(x)$, since it is not immediately obvious that $x^2 (\log x - 1) + \log x + 1 > 0$ for $ x > 1$:  the first term is actually **negative** until $x \ge e$, so in the interval $1 < x < e$, your claim is not yet formally justified.

Answer (score 8):

We may write the inequality as $$0 \le \log x \le \frac{x-x^{-1}}{2}.$$  The LHS is trivial.  At $x = 1$, we have RHS equality, so to show that $(x-x^{-1})/2 - \log x \ge 0$, it suffices to show that $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{x-x^{-1}}{2} - \log x\right] = \frac{(x-1)^2}{2x^2}\ge 0 $$ for $x > 1$.  This of course is also trivial.

Answer (score 6):

By setting $x=e^t$, your inequality is equivalent to:
$$\forall t>0,\qquad 0\leq t \leq \sinh(t)\tag{1} $$
that is trivial since $\sinh(t)$ is a positive convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\sinh'(0)=1$.

Comment: This verifies the inequality for $x\gt1$, which is specified in the question. However, we can go further by noting that for all $x\gt0$ and $x\ne1$, this is equivalent to $\frac{\sinh(t)}t\ge1$ for all $t\ne0$.

Answer (score 3):

**$\boldsymbol{x\gt1}$ (as specified)**

Consider
$$
f(x)=2x\log(x)-\left(x^2-1\right)\tag{1}
$$
Since $e^x\ge1+x$ for all $x$, we have $x\ge1+\log(x)$ for all $x\gt0$. Therefore
$$
f'(x)=2+2\log(x)-2x\le0\tag{2}
$$
and $f$ is monotonically decreasing for $x\gt0$. Since $f(1)=0$, we have that $f(x)\le0$ for $x\ge1$.

That is, for $x\gt1$,
$$
2x\log(x)\le\left(x^2-1\right)\tag{3}
$$
Dividing by $x^2-1$, which is positive, and noting that $x\log(x)$ is also positive, gives
$$
0\le\frac{x\log(x)}{x^2-1}\le\frac12\tag{4}
$$

---

**$\boldsymbol{0\lt x\lt1}$ (as a bonus)**

For $0\lt x\lt1$, both $x\log(x)\lt0$ and $x^2-1\lt0$. Therefore, since $f$ is decreasing and $f(1)=0$, we have that for $0\lt x\lt1$,
$$
2x\log(x)\ge\left(x^2-1\right)\tag{5}
$$
Dividing by $x^2-1$ now gives
$$
0\le\frac{x\log(x)}{x^2-1}\le\frac12\tag{6}
$$
for $0\lt x\lt1$ as well.

Comment: Alas, $x > \frac{1}{2}(x+1)$ for $x > 1$; otherwise this would be a nice proof.

Comment: @Unit: indeed. Thanks. I have provided a, hopefully correct, proof.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I fixed the answer in response to Unit's comment. If a problem exists, I will fix it or delete this answer.

Comment: The downvoter was Unit.

Answer (score 2):

Bounding the integral by a [trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) on the interval $[1,x]$ we get for $x>1$
$$\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}t < \tfrac12(1+\frac1x)(x-1) = \frac{x^2-1}{2x}.$$